# Android AdMob doesn't show

Tags: android, admob

i have add on my app the AdMob. I have read and done all istruction by firebase and this is my grandle file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.52'
compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
compile 'com.twotoasters.clusterkraf:library:1.0.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.uncopt:android.justified:1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'

//compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.3@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
compile 'com.karumi:dexter:2.3.0'
compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i have add on firebase the finger print of my app and package name

this is the code layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/adLinear"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now whe i run the app i don't see a real advertising but the general adMob advertising that say the dimension of my banner.
There is something wrang in my code or to see the real advertising i must public on google play store my app?

Thanks

When i run app i see this similar image
[image]

i would like if is correct and if i must publish app on google play to see a real advrtise

Comment: try adSize="BANNER"

Comment: You need to create a live ad unit ID on admob.com, and insert that to your AdView (where the `ads:adUnitId` attribute is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/adLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

in java file to show ad use this

```
private void adView() {
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.admob_banner_id));
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Replace your code with this.Actually the problem is ad size is greater than your layout size, that is why you are facing this problem.

Comment: I have set your code my when i run app i see always the banner of AdMob test and not real advertise. I must publish on playstore to see real advertise?

Comment: I have add a image of my result...i would like if i must publish on google play app to see a real advertise

Comment: @APPGIS, you _don't_ need to publish your app to the Play store to see live ads.